# MySQL: FULL OUTER JOIN - How do I merge one column?

Tags: sql, mysql, union, full-outer-join

I have a question regarding a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL. I have two (or more tables):

```
table1      table2
id  value   id  value2
1   a       1   b
2   c       3   d
3   e       4   f
```

I have used this query to get my join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.`id`=table2.`id`
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM table1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.`id`=table2.`id`
```

to get:

```
id   value1  id   value2 
1    a       1    b
2    c       NULL NULL
3    e       3    d
NULL NULL    4    f
```

My problem is that I don't manage to simultaneously collapse the two id columns into one column to get this:

```
id   value1  value2 
1    a       b
2    c       NULL
3    e       d
4    NULL    f
```

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Use:

```
    SELECT t1.id,
           t1.value,
           t2.value2 
      FROM table1 t1
 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
UNION
    SELECT t2.id,
           t1.value,
           t2.value2
      FROM TABLE1 t1
RIGHT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```

The `UNION` operator removes row/record duplicates, so you have to define/list the columns appropriately.

### Scripts:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`table1`;
CREATE TABLE  `example`.`table1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `value` varchar(45) NOT NULL default ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'e');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`table2`;
CREATE TABLE  `example`.`table2` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `value2` varchar(45) NOT NULL default ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1, 'b'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'f');
```

Edit: Fixed line above

Comment: What if I have to do this on sqlite. It supports on LEFT JOINs ?

Answer (score 74):

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
t1.value1,
t2.value2
FROM table1 t1
FULL JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

For what I think you are trying to do, I would suggest using a FULL OUTER JOIN instead:

```
SELECT ISNULL(t1.id, t2.id) AS id, t1.value1, t2.value2
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: This will return a 1064 - syntax error because MySQL doesn't support the [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) -- that's why the OP didn't use it.

Comment: As OMG Ponies said, unfortunately MySQL doesn't support the FULL OUTER JOIN syntax and it has to be simulated by different means. I found this helpful: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/