# SQL Join to return null rows from both left and right table

Tags: sql, mysql, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL: FULL OUTER JOIN - How do I merge one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415109/mysql-full-outer-join-how-do-i-merge-one-column)

Real simple question, but have completely confused myself.

Say I have the following tables:

## tbl1

id - count1
a  - 7
b  - 4
d  - 2

## tbl2

id - count2
a  - 3
c  - 4

I want to create a table that gives the following result:

## tbl_temp

id - count1  - count2
a  -  7  -  3
b  - 4  -  null
c  -  null  -  4
d  -  2  - null

What type of join do I need to use?

Cheers,

Ben

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ideally you would want to use a FULL OUTER JOIN but it is [not supported in MySQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18003). Instead you can emulate it using a LEFT and RIGHT OUTER JOIN (or another LEFT with the tables reversed) and UNION ALL the results.

```
SELECT
    tbl1.id,
    tbl1.count1,
    tbl2.count2
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2
ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id

UNION ALL

SELECT
    tbl2.id,
    tbl1.count1,
    tbl2.count2
FROM tbl2
LEFT JOIN tbl1
ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
WHERE tbl1.id IS NULL

ORDER BY id
```

Results:

```
id  count1  count2
a   7       3     
b   4       NULL  
c   NULL    4     
d   2       NULL
```

Comment: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/ look here for different solutions.