# SQL Full Outer Join on same column in same table

Tags: sql, oracle, full-outer-join

This may be more of a design issue than anything, but I'm hoping it's possible without too much voodoo.

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM stuff;

 id   grp
  1     a
  2     a
  3     a
  1     b
  2     b
  4     b
```

And I want to get something like this (with the ID's grouped in columns):

```
a.id    b.id
   1       1
   2       2
   3    null
null       4
```

Is this possible? I've tried the following query...

```
SELECT a.id, b.id FROM stuff a
FULL OUTER JOIN stuff b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.grp = 'a' AND b.grp = 'b';
```

... but I only get the common nodes:

```
a.id    b.id
   1       1
   2       2
```

I've also tried playing around with the JOIN ON and WHERE but can't seem to get the desired result.

The closest question I could find online is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415109/mysql-full-outer-join-how-do-i-merge-one-column), but I couldn't get UNION to work either.

Performance isn't an issue, and I can assume there are only 2 groups.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happened when you followed the answer to the other question and tried to use `UNION`?

Comment: I got results similar to what you'd get with Gordon's suggestion below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're doing the wrong thing first, and attempting to fix it up afterwards. That's not going to work.

The things you want to join are `select * from stuff where grp = 'a'` and `select * from stuff where grp = 'b'`. So join those:

```
select a.ID as a, b.ID as b from
  (select * from stuff where grp = 'a') a
full join
  (select * from stuff where grp = 'b') b
on b.id = a.id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f436/3)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Your SQL worked perfectly. I can't believe I didn't catch that.